# What library is puts@@GLIBC_2.2.5 in

Tags: x86, glibc, intel-mkl

I am trying to statically link mkl into assembly code, with the following:

ld -L/home/ziheng/intel/compilers_and_libraries/linux/mkl/lib/intel64 -L /home/ziheng/intel/compilers_and_libraries/linux/lib/intel64/ -lm -lmkl_intel_lp64 -lmkl_intel_thread -lmkl_core -lmkl_blacs_openmpi_ilp64 -liomp5 -lpthread -ldl bump.o

It shows that I have undefined reference to:
puts@@GLIBC_2.2.5

Does anyone know what flag I am missing?

Comment: I guess you already did the obvious, linking against libc, is that right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This command:

> `ld -L/home/ziheng/intel/compilers_and_libraries/linux/mkl/lib/intel64 -L /home/ziheng/intel/compilers_and_libraries/linux/lib/intel64/ -lm -lmkl_intel_lp64 -lmkl_intel_thread -lmkl_core -lmkl_blacs_openmpi_ilp64 -liomp5 -lpthread -ldl bump.o`

is incorrect on every platform that GIBC supports.

In general, user-level code should *never* link anything directly with `ld` -- always use appropriate compiler driver (likely `gcc` here).

In addition, putting libraries before object files on the link line will fail with most unix linkers (at least for archive libraries).

Correct command would be something like this:

```
gcc bump.o \
    -L/home/ziheng/intel/compilers_and_libraries/linux/mkl/lib/intel64 \
    -L/home/ziheng/intel/compilers_and_libraries/linux/lib/intel64 \
    -lmkl_intel_lp64 -lmkl_blacs_openmpi_ilp64 -lmkl_intel_thread -lmkl_core \
    -liomp5 -lm -lpthread -ldl
```

P.S.

> What library is puts@@GLIBC_2.2.5 in

It's in `libc`.

P.P.S.

> I am trying to statically link mkl

There is nothing on your command line that implies static linking. You'll need to add `-static` for that.